# app engine deployment through cloud shell hangs without error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am deploying a app engine application through cloud shell. I have deployed it a lot of times, but currently when ever I deploy it i gets hanged at the below position and nothing happens:

```
myname@cloudshell:~stackdriver-metrics-export/list_metrics (my-project)$ gcloud app deploy
Services to deploy:
descriptor:      [/home/myname/stackdriver-metrics-export/list_metrics/app.yaml]
source:          [/home/myname/stackdriver-metrics-export/list_metrics]
target project:  [my-project]
target service:  [list-metrics]
target version:  [20200703t225313]
target url:      [http://list-metrics.my-project.uc.r.appspot.com]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
Beginning deployment of service [list-metrics]...
```

// it gets stuck here and nothing happens afterwards I even restarted cloudshell lot of times but the same result, there is no change in the cursor position also. No error is also thrown

Please help me as i am new to cloud shell and google cloud.

Comment: You changed nothing that can be block the deployment? How long did you wait?

Comment: please deploy with gcloud app deploy --log-http --verbosity=debug and share the output. This probably will help you to understand whats happening. Alpso if you are deploying a flex app keep in mind that them take more time than an standard app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now, I am not sure what is the reason, but after i try to download a project from cloudshell to my local machine, strangely I found the project in one of the cloud shell directories itself as duplicate, and I have cleaned all of that, so still not sure of the reason

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have symbolic link or very large file in the same directory.  That will cause the system to take along time packaging your deployment.